# How Can I Generate a Separate Image of each Segmentation in a Picture?

Tags: python, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, image-segmentation

I'm trying to make my image data-labelling process a bit easier for myself. What I'm trying to do is I'm trying to segment an image using detectron2 instance segmentation models (https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/main/MODEL_ZOO.md). Honestly, I don't mind using any other segmentation model like DETR or something similar that could get the job done.

Essentially, I'm feeding an image like the following into the model: [Unsegmented Tennis Match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Hx6.jpg)

I then use a segmentation model to generate the following output: [Segmented Tennis Match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oyQa.jpg).

However, what I am trying to do is get each instance in the image as its own image (kind of like a sticker). In other words, after inputting the very first image above of an unsegmented Tennis Match, I'd like to have the following images downloaded to the same folder I'm running my Python file:

- [Segmented Tennis Ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNr6w.png)
- [Segmented Tennis Racket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkZJ4.png)
- [Segmented Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R47u.gif)

If anyone could provide me with a simple script to do so, that would be great (it would be more so appreciated if I could run and test this script on a Google Colab notebook directly). Thanks in advance!

I tried using the Detectron2 segmentation models by themselves but all this does is overlay masks onto the original image. Instead, I would like to have separate instances in the image instead of masks of different colours displayed on the original picture.

This is how my code looks so far:

```
import torch

import detectron2
from detectron2.utils.logger import setup_logger
setup_logger()

from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer
from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog, DatasetCatalog

import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

image = cv2.imread("./RogerFederer.jpg")
cv2_imshow(image)


cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x.yaml")

cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.6


viz = Visualizer(image[:,:,::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]))
output = viz.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
cv2_imshow(output.get_image()[:,:,::-1])
```

Again, I'm open to changing my code or using a different image segmentation library

Comment: I've come across your post looking to do the same. Your problem is slightly simplified compared to mine in that you probably only have one object of each type. By your sample outputs, it seems like you are able to separate out the different objects. From there, it would be a matter of applying a mask for each object to extract just that bit. Then you can crop around the whitespace for each one. That should work.